# PANDAS : join a string with a part of a string from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ShipTo': ["", "", "", ""], 'Item_Description':["SYD_QANTAS ", "SYD_QANTAS", "PVG_SHANGHAI", "HKG_JARDINE"]})
```

I'd like to create a string merge in the column ShipTo "B" + first 3 characters from the column "Item_Description" so the result would be:

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

TRy this,

```
df["ShipTo"] = "B"+df1['Item_Description'].str[:3]
```

O/P:

```
  ShipTo Item_Description
0   BSYD      SYD_QANTAS 
1   BSYD       SYD_QANTAS
2   BPVG     PVG_SHANGHAI
3   BHKG      HKG_JARDINE
```

Slice first 3 elemnts of Item Description column and merge with your string literal.